# Small window when starting the game (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I already compiled the game and when I launch it the window doesn’t become the size that I set in player settings (1080x1920).Perhaps the problem is in windows because I can tilt the window.rebooting the system and updating the drivers did not help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgjhk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNVko.png)

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62916566/ui-is-shown-too-small-in-final-built-game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

editor is always scalable, do a build and run the exe