# UI is shown too small in final (built) game

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm a newbie to Unity and am learning. I've made my first game which is a simple platformer, along with a main menu. The game also has some text GUI elements. When I run it in Unity's built-in player, the GUI looks fine, but when I build the project and run the game using the .exe, the UI is scaled down.

I'm attaching some screenshots below to clarify this.

[image]

(As seen in Unity player)

[image]

(As seen in game)

Also, the game UI also looks scaled down:

[image]

(As seen in player)

[image]

(As seen in game)

I want the in-game UI to be exactly like the one seen in the Unity player.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Is your canvas set to scale with screen size, and the UI elements making proper use of the rect transform's capabilities such as [anchors and stretching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Canvas can be set to scale with different settings if you want it to be accurate you should choose:

**-Scale With Screen Size**

Using the Scale With Screen Size mode, positions and sizes can be specified according to the pixels of a specified reference resolution. If the current screen resolution is larger than the reference resolution, the Canvas will keep having only the resolution of the reference resolution, but will scale up in order to fit the screen. If the current screen resolution is smaller than the reference resolution, the Canvas will similarly be scaled down to fit.

Comment: That is resulting to an over-expanded UI (both in editor and game)....

Answer (score 1):

**1-** Go to your Canvas and select the **Scale With Screen Size** option

**2-** After that, make sure that the **Reference Resolution** is the same as the `Game Window` resolution in your Unity layout, I leave here an example:[image]

As you can see, the resolution set on my Game window is (1024x768) and the reference resolution of the Canvas too.

Comment: Well, that didn't make any difference. My game window just says 16:9 so I set the reference resolution to 1920X1080 (which is also my screen resolution.) Am I making a mistake? Oh, and also, the EventSystem (I dunno what it is) is larger than the canvas, can it be the reason?

Comment: What do you mean with larger?  The Event System is the component that registers the touch actions in the screen, but it doesn't do anything with the resolution

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized.....When I'm increasing the reference resolution, the canvas size is increasing alright, but the other components (buttons text and a panel) are not. They are fixed. How do I fix that?

Comment: I suggest you not to change the reference resolution, because the entire UI will be scaled up if the screen resolution is larger and scaled down if the screen resolution is smaller.

Comment: I have no idea what was wrong, but setting the reference resolution to 1920x1080 and deleting and remaking the background panel fixed it!